# Check whether a class exists in any row of a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table (simplified for this question):

```
<table><br>
  <tr onclick="selectRow"><br>
    <td>table data</td><br>
    <td>table data</td><br>
    <td>table data</td><br>
  </tr><br>
  <tr class="selected" onclick="selectRow"><br>
    <td>table data</td><br>
    <td>table data</td><br>
    <td>table data</td><br>
  </tr><br>
</table>
```

`class="selected"` is a result of clicking on the row.
I want to make a button that when clicked, would return true if there is a row with the class 'selected', and false if there is not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
function checkExist(){
       var myTr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

       for(var i=myTr.length; i--;){
           if(myTr[i].className.match('(^|\\s+)selected(\\s+|$)')){
               alert('true');//return true;
               return;
           }
       }
       alert('false'); //return false
}
```

and basically attach to a button or link like this:

```
<table>
    <tr onclick="selectRow">
        <td>table data</td>
        <td>table data</td>
        <td>table data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='selected' onclick="selectRow">
        <td>table data</td>
        <td>table data</td>
        <td>table data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<a href='#' onclick='checkExist()'>click me to find out</a>
```

Comment: +1 because OP didn't mention jQuery... but really, who writes their own CSS selection code and duplicates it all over the code? If someone really doesn't want to include jQuery, they should at least use http://sizzlejs.com/, which is only 3Kb

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks, mate.  I don't usually use jQuery i use [Mootools](http://mootools.net) for readability and elegant code.

Comment: I don't use jQuery either, I use Ext-JS. The main point is that CSS selection should be abstracted, so mootools, prototype (ugh), Ext, YUI, or at least, re-invent the wheel according to your needs. Just don't sprinkle this kind of code all over your app!

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a library? Using jQuery this could be as simple as http://jsfiddle.net/andersand/QAb4s/

My experience is that by using a JS framework makes me not have to worry that much about cross browser compatibility, while also having increased development speed

Answer (score 0):

Without using an external library, you'd have to do something like the following:

1. Get all the rows in the table and start looping through them
2. Check each row's `className` property for your class (`selected`).

   - If you're only dealing with the one class, you can just compare:
     `tr.className === 'selected'`
   - If a row can have more than one class, you'll probably want to use regular expressions. Something like `/\bselected\b/`
3. As soon as you get a match, cancel the loop and return true immediately

For extra credit, you could put all of this into a function that takes the class you're looking for and the table in which to look as arguments.

Assignments are due first thing Monday morning.